# Another memory leak using NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have provided more information on the code. The `checkstatusthread()` is called after every 5 seconds. `ipItemsArray` object used below stores the XML coming from the server.

// XMLAppDelegate.h

```
@interface XMLAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSMutableString *hostStr2;
    NSData *dataURL2;
    NSString *playlistdata;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *hostStr2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *dataURL2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *playlistdata;
@end
```

//  XMLAppDelegate.m

```
-(void)checkstatusthread
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    hostStr2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@/getplaylist.php?ip=%@",yourip,restip];

    dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr2 ]];  

    playlistdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    ipItemsArray = [playlistdata componentsSeparatedByString:@"|^|"];

    [hostStr2 release]; 
    [playlistdata release];

    status =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [status retain];

     if([[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:0]isEqualToString:@"0001"])
     { 
        serverOutput1 =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:1];
        [serverOutput1 retain];

        nowplaying =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:2];    
        [nowplaying retain];

        tracklocation=[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:3];
        [requestlocation retain];

        requestlocation=[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:4];
        temp_app =[tracklocation intValue];


     }

        [serverOutput1 retain];
        [nowplaying retain];
        [serverOutput1 retain];
        [nowplaying retain];
        [tracklocation retain]; 
        [requestlocation retain];

        // checkstatus() called
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkstatus) 
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:false];

    [pool drain];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [dataURL2 release];
    [playlistdata release];
    [ipItemsArray release];
}
```

The line **`NSArray *ipItemsArray = [playlistdata componentsSeparatedByString:@"|^|"];`** gives me a memory leak when I run the leaks instrument in Xcode 4.2. have tried all possible things on this, but feel like something needs to be added. Can someone please help me out.

Here is the Screenshot of the leaked object. Also i noticed my app doesn't call Dealloc method.

[image]

Comment: are you releasing playlistdata and hostStr2 when done?

Comment: Why are you retaining  status twice?

Comment: I have removed one of the status retain line. That was printed by mistake.

Comment: I have used Automatic Reference Counting for automatically managing objects as I was using XCode 4.2. My issue is resolved with no leaks. I am not sure if this will work fine on older versions of iOS and whether it will be approved by Apple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that is leaking is "status". I infer that it is an iVar. When you do this:

```
 status =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:0];
[status retain];
```

The second time these lines get executed, the previously stored value in status is not released properly, hence a leak. You should ideally be doing this:

```
if(status) {
    [status release];
}
status =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex:0];
[status retain];
```

This will solve your leak shown in instruments. (Assuming ARC is not being used)

Comment: The same must be done with the other iVars. Else use retain properties and access them using self.status, and so on. In that case you can directly assign and dont have to release the previous value

Answer (score 1):

actually the Analyzer is pointing you to the this line of code:

```
NSMutableString *hostStr2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://   %@/getplaylist.php?ip=%@",yourip,restip];
```

which you have allocated and not release yet.

You need to release it.

Comment: playlistdata is also not being released.

Comment: `playlistdata` was class level, so that's why I don't pointed out.

Comment: I am releasing all the three objects. But still it is showing a memory leak. Do I need to use some other classes or any other solution?

Comment: Three??  What is the third object you are releasing...only hostStr2 and playlistdata are being alloc'ed and need to be released.  hoststr2 is a local variable and could not reasonably be released outside this function.  If playlistdata is just released in the class dealloc, but this function is called more than once, it will also leak.  We need more context than these four lines to help with this.

Comment: @AdilSoomro: I have edited the question and provided more code to help you understand it better. please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

All you have done is correct. Not every leak that is shown by Leaks Instrument is currently a Leak.

I recommend you to use at first step the Clang Analyzer XCode -> Products -> Analyse. This shows you some potential Leaks. And after this you should use Heapshot Analysis http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: Thanks. Analyse shows me no issues. I will try the link given here and use this method and come back.

Comment: By using the Allocations tool, Mark Heap analysis points again to this line of the code.
       `NSArray *ipItemsArray = [playlistdata componentsSeparatedByString:@"|^|"];`